# What happens to static class's variables and methods when libraries are statically and dinamically linked

Tags: c++, static, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-variables

The following escenario is intriguing me.

`(A)` source code library.

`(B)` a shared library which includes `(A)`

`(C)` a static library which includes `(A)`

`(D)`, a top level program linking with `(B)` and `(C)`.

Previously I read the following answer and understood that if the linkage is static the variables are truly static and exist only once in the whole program, but if the linkage is dynamic the static variables exist as many times as the library is included.
[What happens to static variables when libraries are statically linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909035/what-happens-to-static-variables-when-libraries-are-statically-linked)

In example if I include N times an static library with the following code, the `__immediately_lambda_call` is triggered N times but access to the same `gMyClass`.

```
static MyClass& GetSingleton() {
    static std::once_flag flag;
    static MyClass* gMyClass;
    std::call_once(flag, [&]() { gMyClass = new MyClass(); });
    return *gMyClass;
}

static const auto __immediately_lambda_call = []() {
    auto& gMyClass = GetSingleton();
    return true;
}();
```

But what happens when the same code is included as dynamic library and static library.

***Feel free to ignore the next paragraph.*** I'm more concerned about how memory is shared between static and dynamic library.

The question is because the top level program `(D)` randomly throws me a `double free memory` error in a more complex code that I summarize as the following code and I don't understand why, but adding `__attribute__((visibility( hidden ))` when the dynamic library is compiled seems to fix the issue.

```
static const int gMyArr[2] = {1,2};
static const int gMyNum = 1;

class API_STATIC_DYNAMIC MyOtherClass
{
public:
    MyOtherClass()
     : mMatrix(new int[20])
    {}
    
    MyOtherClass()
    {
       delete[] mMatrix;
    }
    
    void doSomething()
    {
        int d = gMyArr[0];
    }

    static int gMatrix[10];
    static int gNumber;
    
private:
    int *mMatrix;
}
```

**Edit LIBRARY:**

API.h

```
#if defined(STATIC_LIB)
    #define API_STATIC_DYNAMIC 
#else
    #define API_STATIC_DYNAMIC __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) // removed "default"
#endif
```

MYLIB.h

```
class MyLibApi
{
public:
    void doSomething();
    
private:
    class MyLibImp;
    MyLibImp *mPimpl;
}
```

MYLIB.cpp

```
class MyLibImp()
{
public:
    MyOtherClass myOther;
}

void MyLibApi::doSomething()
{
    mPimpl->myOther->doSomething();
}
```

**Edit APP:**

```
int main()
{
   MyLibApi api;
   api.doSomething();
   MyOtherClass other;
   other.doSomething();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question please. Consider publishing your C++ code on http://github.com/ with some open source license

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to static class's variables and methods when libraries are statically and dynamically linked ?

## This is operating system (or implementation) specific.

**For *Linux***, read the (quite long) paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and also [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and also [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/). Read also a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html), see also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read later the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (or the specification of a more recent [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) standard).

### To simplify, on Linux:

**for statically linked libraries** : constructors of static data are run before  `main` by [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0), and destructors of static data are run after `main`. *Some* constructors initialize [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) required for `virtual` methods.

**for shared libraries** :  Constructors of static data are run either at [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) time, or at [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) time (so then before `main`). Destructors are run at `dlclose` time, or after main by `ld.so`. Read details of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and other relevant [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

The order of constructor running *could* be related to the order of linking your libraries at build time. If you link with `g++ a.o b.o -lxa -lyb` it is *likely* that static constructors are run in `a.o`, then in `b.o`, then in `libxa.a`, then in `libyb.so`, but perhaps those from shared libraries could be run first.

You could use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger and set a breakpoint in *some* of *your* constructors. You might want to compile *all* your C++ code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -fno-inline` for debugging purposes.

---

> the top level program (D) randomly throws me a double free memory

Regarding your double free issue, consider using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and/or the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Read more about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

Of course, enable all warnings and debug info when compiling, so use at learn `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. With [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/), try its new [static analyzer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) option. Consider also using [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/).

> I'm more concerned about how memory is shared between static and dynamic library.

Remember that a given [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has a single [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Use [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to understand it (or programmatically, with [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), from inside your program, `/proc/self/maps`). Read more about [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and use [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html), [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html), [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) on your (or other) executables and shared libraries. Use also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand the runtime behavior of your program.